# Deducing the powers of a Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

I have a Markov matrix that looks like this:

\begin{align}
 P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - p && q \\ p && 1 - q \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, I want to prove that the following formula by eigenvalues

\begin{align}
 P^n = \dfrac{1}{p+q}\begin{pmatrix} q && q \\ p && p \end{pmatrix} + \dfrac{(1-p-q)^n}{p+q}\begin{pmatrix} p && -q \\ -p && q \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Currently, I have found that eigenvalues are 1 and 1-p-q, and based on \begin{align} \det(P - \lambda E) = 0 \end{align} I did get the two matrices in the formula above, however, I have no idea about how to write the relationship between them, please help me. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What were the corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: As far as I know, they are (q/p, 1) and (1, -1). I am not sure if these are correct. I am aware that the proof is related to UPU^{-1} = D which is known as Diagonalization. But, I have yet to recognize something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_2 = 1 - p - q$, along with their eigenvectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
q/p\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$. So you can diagonalize your matrix as $P = VDV^{-1}$, where $V = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 & v_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
q/p & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$, and $D = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 - p - q
\end{pmatrix}$. (In general, if $P$ is $n \times n$ and you found eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ and independent eigenvectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$, then you can diagonalize it as $P = VDV^{-1}$, where $V = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 & \dots & v_n
\end{pmatrix}$ - i.e., arrange the eigenvectors in columns, and $D = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \ & \ \\
\ & \ddots  & \ \\
\ & \ & \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix}$.)

When you take $n$-th power, you get
\begin{align*}
P^n & = VD^n V^{-1}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}
q/p & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & (1 - p - q)^n
\end{pmatrix} V^{-1}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}
q/p & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & (1 - p - q)^n
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p}{p + q} & \frac{p}{p + q}\\
\frac{p}{p + q} & -\frac{q}{p + q}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

If you actually compute this matrix multiplication, you will get
$$ \frac{p}{p + q}\begin{pmatrix}
q/p + (1 - p - q)^n & q/p - q/p(1 - p - q)^n\\
1 - (1 - p - q)^n & 1 + q/p(1 - p - q)^n
\end{pmatrix} $$
You can break it into two parts - one that has a factor of $(1 - p - q)^n$, which simplifies to $\frac{(1 - p - q)^n}{p + q}\begin{pmatrix}
p & -q\\
-p & q
\end{pmatrix}$, the other without $(1 - p - q)^n$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{p + q} \begin{pmatrix}
q & q\\
p & p
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive procedure, it is really helpful!

Comment: @Sonamu No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

New to this website so I apologize for the format. But can you show how you solve for those eigenvalues. I can’t get the Algebra right and need a hand. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sorry, couldn’t find the area for a question addition.

Comment: The definition of eigenvalue is $Px = λx$, and then $(P - λ)x = 0$. This is equivalent to det(P - λE) = 0. 

\begin{equation}
   p =
  \begin{pmatrix}
     1 - p - λ && q \\
           p      && 1 - q - λ
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Or use Cayley-Hamilton, you can directly write down $λ^2 - (2-p-q)λ + (1-p-q) = 0$, just solve this quadratic equation.

Comment: Apologize for the misunderstanding of p. It should be $det(P - λE)$